# Passing a Non-Value in a mySQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

The following is the query that I'm trying to get to work.

```
$array = array();

SELECT * FROM ENTRIES
WHERE
   entry_id = '12'
OR
   entry_id_extra IN ('$array')
```

This is of course simplified. The problem is that it works great if the array has items and it returns everything fine. But if the array has no item it fails to work.

What is the correct way to construct this statement that doesn't break if there are no items in the array? I tried `IN ('NULL','$array')` but that didnt work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the `OR` portion of the where clause go through a conditional check:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE entry_id = 12"

if (count($array) > 0) {
    $sql .= ' OR entry_id_extra IN ($array)';
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. The OR operator was left hanging if the array was empty which would have caused a fail

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(...);
$array = array_map('mysql_escape_string', $array); // make sure it's safe
$query = "SELECT   *
          FROM     entries
          WHERE    entry_id = '12'"
       . (count($array) > 0
         ? " OR    entry_id_extra IN ('" . implode("','", $array) . "')" 
         : "");

// echo the query to see what it looks like (optional)
echo "<pre>{$query}</pre>";
```

You can use `implode`, but also make sure you escape the values so quotes don't set the query off.